# Custom Cycling presence (discord.js v14)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
require("dotenv").config()
const {Client,ActivityType} = require("discord.js")
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client 
     */
    async execute(client) {
        console.log(`✅ ${client.user.tag} is Ready!`);
        const activities = [{name: "Made By andrexdev",type: ActivityType.Playing},
        {name: `${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers`,type: ActivityType.Watching},
        {name: `${client.users.cache.size} People`,type: ActivityType.Watching}]
        counter = 0
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(counter == activities.length+1) counter = 0
            client.user.setActivity({
                activities: [activities[counter]],
                status: "online"
            })
            counter+=1;
        }, 5000);
        
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOOSE_CONNECTION_STRING).then(() => {
            console.log("✅ Connected to MongoDB!")
        })
    }
}
```

it gives an error:
[It gives this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr4Zp.png)

i want it to cycle through all the presences in the array
no matter why i try i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You are checking when the counter is above the `length+1`, meaning you encounter an error at `activities[activities.length]` which is `undefined`.

A much easier way to approach rotating through the activities is like so, using the modulo (`%`) operation to keep the `counter` looping: 0, 1, 2 but then back to 0 and repeating.

```js
        const activities = [{name: "Made By andrexdev",type: ActivityType.Playing},
        {name: `${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers`,type: ActivityType.Watching},
        {name: `${client.users.cache.size} People`,type: ActivityType.Watching}]
        counter = 0
        setTimeout(() => {
            client.user.setActivity({
                activities: [activities[counter]],
                status: "online"
            })
            counter = (counter + 1) % activities.length;
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: Doesnt work
TypeError [InvalidType]: Supplied activities[0].name is not a string.